# How to use gradle to link a jar in lib?

Tags: java, jar, gradle

The project looks like:

Project

/src  /a.java

/lib  /B.jar

/bin

(a.java use some class in B.jar)

How to link B.jar and build the project by gradle?

Answer (score 8):

First of all create a new build script named `build.gradle` on the root level of your project. You will need to apply the Java plugin and set your source directory to `src` as it doesn't use the default project layout. We also assign your JAR file dependency to the `compile` configuration. Running `gradle build` will compile your code, run tests (which you don't have) and assemble your module's artifact.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: 'B.jar') 
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple .jar files gradle will also take a wildcard as follows: 

`compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')`