# Including a jar using gradle

Tags: java, jar, compilation, gradle

How do you do the equivalent of adding a jar to the classpath when using gradle?

I have been searching and reading the doc but i cannot get it to compile.

Edit: As pointed out below there is in fact a previous question about this very issue.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058609/how-to-use-gradle-to-link-a-jar-in-lib)

Answer (score 2):

If you plan later to switch to a real repository, you can define a repository in local library folder first following similar conventions as any other Maven repo uses:

```
repositories {
  flatDir name: "local-lib", dirs: "$projectDir/lib"
}

dependencies {    
  compile ':avalon-framework-api:4.3.1'
  compile ':avalon-framework-impl:4.3.1'
}
```

`lib` folder content:

```
avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar 
avalon-framework-impl-4.3.1.jar
```