# Grails / Cobertura report - conditional coverage doesn't make sense

Tags: grails, cobertura

What could cause something like this:

[image: coverage report fragment]

The line `def result` shows only 2/6 branches covered, even though it has NO BRANCHES, while the following line, which actually has a conditional, is ok.

What's going on?  I verified that the `cobertura.ser` is getting cleaned up between builds.

Comment: Is `result` down the lane?

Comment: yes, result is assigned later on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**any idea where I can get the source for that JAR?**

> [jar](https://github.com/renataogarcia/disableOptimizationsTransformation/downloads) and [souce code](https://github.com/renataogarcia/disableOptimizationsTransformation) for disableOptimizationsTransformation

**Also - any idea how to include that JAR on classpath ONLY for the test-app build phase?**

```
// Remove the jar before the war is bundled
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
  delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/DisableOptimizationsTransformation-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
}
```

**from [other post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979323/how-do-i-add-a-jar-to-the-classpath-of-a-grails-project-only-for-test-scope)**

Comment: Will that really only apply to the test-app build phase?

Comment: Thanks! And to make use of this jar in Gradle, I found this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11063656/95750

Answer (score 5):

Same discussion also appeared in the official forum, see [Branch coverage issues](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Branch-coverage-issues-td5686725.html) .

@rgarcia gave an excellent little tool [jar](https://github.com/downloads/renataogarcia/disableOptimizationsTransformation/DisableOptimizationsTransformation-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) to disable the AST optimization so that Cobertura is able to compute the coverage correctly.

To use the jar, just put it in your `myapp\lib` folder and then `test-app -coverage`:)

Comment: any idea where I can get the source for that JAR?  Also - any idea how to include that JAR on classpath ONLY for the test-app build phase?

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed the same thing in our grails projects - I think this is caused by the "optimization" branches the groovy compiler creates.

For example - this code

```
def deleteSomething(params) {
   def result
   if(params.something && params.somethingelse)
      result = "something"
   else result = "something else"
}
```

looks like this when compiled

```
public Object deleteSomething(Object params)
{
   CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray(); Object result = null; if ((!BytecodeInterface8.isOrigZ()) || (__$stMC) || (BytecodeInterface8.disabledStandardMetaClass())) {
      if (((DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(arrayOfCallSite[2].callGetProperty(params))) && (DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(arrayOfCallSite[3].callGetProperty(params))) ? 1 : 0) != 0) {
         String str1 = "something"; result = str1; return str1; } else {
         String str2 = "something else"; result = str2; return str2;
      }
   }
   else if (((DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(arrayOfCallSite[4].callGetProperty(params))) && (DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(arrayOfCallSite[5].callGetProperty(params))) ? 1 : 0) != 0) {
      String str3 = "something"; result = str3; return str3; } else {
      String str4 = "something else"; result = str4; return str4; } return null;
}
```

More discussion [here](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Branch-coverage-issues-td5686725.html).

Comment: Plausible explanation - so how do I fix it in a Grails app?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This confuses me too:(

Comment: @wrschneider99 After some survey, I found a solution, please check my answer.