# How to disable groovy optimizations in grails 2.3.x

Tags: java, grails, optimization, groovy, code-coverage

I am having some problems with my coverage report. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922826/grails-cobertura-report-conditional-coverage-doesnt-make-sense) It seems to be the optimizations groovy  branches.

The answer says that I should drop [this jar](https://github.com/renataogarcia/disableOptimizationsTransformation) in my lib directory and run "test-app -coverage". But it is still not working.  I think its because I am using grails 2.3.x and groovy 2.x instead of groovy 1.8 (the solution is very old)

How do I use this jar? or the solution is diferent for new groovy compilers?

Some examples of my problem with the coverage report

[image]

and

[image]

I am using oracle java 7 build 24.51-b03 in linux

Comment: did you ensure you also did a clean before? The global transformation you have to build from the link you mentioned needs to be precompiled and can only work when compiling the target Groovy code.

Comment: no luck so far. What I did was the following

Comment: (sorry, previous comment was incomplete). I have some luck with your comment @blackdrag. What I did was the following. drop .jar in the `lib/` directory. `grails clean` and `grails test-app -unit -coverage`. The examples I uploaded are fixed, but I have lines like this ` render ''` that are in red. Show I open  a new question about this behavior or modify the current one?

Comment: I guess a new one would be best, and close/remove this one. but I am unsure I will be able to answer the new question... maybe one of the real Grails people will be able to. It should not be related to optimizations

Comment: thanks. By grails people you mean to ask in grails forums? thanks again @blackdrag

Comment: by Grails I mean to use the Grails tag ;) Well you did for this one too already

Answer (score 0):

I am closing this question becouse the solution was clean/compile and not other procedure.

The only problem so far with this solution is that there are still redlines in my reports that do not have conditional branches. But I will open a new question