# Grails cobertura support

Tags: grails, dependencies, cobertura

Just added **Cobertura** to project and faced with problem like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922826/grails-cobertura-report-conditional-coverage-doesnt-make-sense).
 How can I add a lib only for test environment to Grails project? 
Or maybe you know a better solution for **Coberture** in **Grails**?

Comment: Can't you set the dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy to be in the "test" phase? Thus only available in the test environment?

Comment: @Joshua Moore Dependencies to what? See the response in question I've provided. The solution is to add a jar that not in any repository

Comment: I was suggesting putting it in a repository, otherwise the question you have linked to is the solution to removing the jar from the lib directory for your project.

Comment: Probably you are right. I have an internal repository on project. Any other ideas how it can be done?